# c# Windows Form Application - How to delete just one item from a listbox?

Tags: c#

Lets say I have these items in my listBox.  I know how to delete all the items (listBox1.Items.Clear();), but how do I delete just one item?

```
listBox1.Items.Add(1000);
listBox1.Items.Add(2000); 
listBox1.Items.Add(3000);
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `RemoveAt(selectedIndex)`

Example : `myListBox.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);`

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for but the "SelectedIndex" part gives me an error (Red zigzags under the words).  I just changed the name of the listbox to fit my solution.  I am new to coding.

Comment: @rathibond - You have to define what `selectedIndex` is. If you have `n` items in the list then `selectedIndex` must be between `0` and `n - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

`listBox1.Items.Remove("2000");` - removes the item between brackets. I believe 2000 got to be in quotations, since it's a string value.

`listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedItem);` - removes the selected item(after you click on it). That can be used for OnClick event or combined with a button click, depends on what you need.

P.S. Here's a link [Add or remove items from listBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983551%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)